# Call entity framework core unit of work from inside Azure queue Run() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In my queue, I'm generating a report that I need to save to the database.

I tried DInjecting my unit of work / repository like this:

```
        [FunctionName("AppExecution")]
        public static void Run(
            [QueueTrigger("some-name", Connection = "ConnectionStrings")]
            string     myQueueItem,
            ILogger    log,
            UnitOfWork Work
            // IRepository<SomeClass> Repo  // <-- doesn't work either :(
        )
        { ... }
```

but it didn't work. I got this error when running:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'AppExecution'.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'Work' to type
> UnitOfWork. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.
> If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus,
> Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
> extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
> builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Any suggestion, please? I really need to save the resulting data back to the database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the class non-static and the function non-static, then inject your objects into the class constructor. There's some description of this in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#use-injected-dependencies). For example:

```
public class AppExecutionFunction
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public AppExecutionFunction(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [FunctionName("AppExecution")]
    public void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("some-name", Connection = "ConnectionStrings")]
        string     myQueueItem,
        ILogger    log)
    {
        _unitOfWork.CallMethod();
    }
}
```